# mysql combined unique keys

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

Is there way in MySQL to have two unique keys and connect them somehow?

for example if i have the following table and 'title'and 'store' are a unique keys

```
id | category | title       | price | store
1  | outdoors | fishing rod | 59.99 | wal-mart
2  | auto     | Penzoil Oil | 9.99  | target
```

and i try to insert the following record. This new record would be ignored because the title is "fishing rod" AND the store is 'wal-mart' and there is an existing record with that title and store

```
   | outdoors | fishing rod | 30.99 | wal-mart
```

but if i attempted to insert the following record it would be accepted because there isn't a record that exists with the title of "fishing rod" and store of "target"

```
   | outdoors | fishing rod | 30.99 | target
```

is this possible with just MySQL?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can define an index on multiple columns, e.g.:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX arbitrary_index_name ON table_name (title, store);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Instead of two separate unique constraints you should create a single unique constraint on both columns.

The `CREATE INDEX` syntax is:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...
```

For your example it would look something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON tbl_name (title,store);
```

You will also have to drop the two incorrect unique indexes that you created.

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) for more details on how to create indexes.

Answer (score 3):

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE INDEX( `title`, `store`);

Comment: Can you some additional information on how your code provides and answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need a [multi-column unique key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can!

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY(title, store);
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. A numeric primary key has many advantages, such as consistency (most tables have it) and simplicity.