# index uniq key does not seems to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing, unique-key

I'm trying to do a kind of friend request for my chat,

so I set a table called `cyb_user_friendlist`

then I've put some tables like that :

```
1   id_friendlist   int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT   
2   from            int(11)     
3   to          int(11)         
4   couple          varchar(11)
5   accept          int(11)     
6   block           int(11)
```

so for each friend request an insert is done to this table with id of sender into from and id of receiver into to, but to make sure that there is only one request per couple I added a field called couple in which there is the concatenation of from and to with a vertical separator |. this field has a uniq key because I want to prevent from multiple records.

the only thing is that it does not seems to work, actualy I added my uniq key to this fields and a primary key to the id_friendlist but it does not work, I can send many request as wanted...

my request $sql to do that is the one below :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cyb_users_friendlist` SET
            `from` = {$from},
            `to` = {$to},
            `couple` = '{$from}|{$to}'";
```

I really do not know where I'm wrong...

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: not sure what the question is here

Comment: the trouble is that it insert also duplicate entry even with the index unique key... I also tried using insert ignore but it does not work

Comment: you dont need 'couple' you can add a unique index on 2 fields. ALTER TABLE `YOUR TABLE NAME` ADD UNIQUE `unique` ( `from` , `to` )

Comment: Can you post the output of `show create table cyb_users_friendlist`? It sounds seems like you didn't create the unique key properly.

Comment: REATE TABLE `cyb_users_friendlist` (
 `id_friendlist` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `couple` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `accept` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `block` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_friendlist`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_friendlist` (`id_friendlist`),
 UNIQUE KEY `couple` (`couple`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding another field which is concatenated of two another when you can just add unique index?

[mysql combined unique keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125727/mysql-combined-unique-keys)

```
ALTER TABLE `YOUR TABLE` ADD UNIQUE `unique` ( `from` , `to` )
```

Comment: no because I need to have the concat for the reciprocity, so you can not send a frienrequest if somebody sent you one, just answer the the previous.

Comment: Then you need two indexes:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html or I just don't understand the problem correctly.

Comment: no because if I add two indexes it means one user can only send one friend request and not many to other users.

Comment: Got it now. Then just use index to concat that two columns and make that index unique. It will be the same as creating _couple_ column.

Else... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `cyb_users_friendlist` SET
        `from` = $from,
        `to` = $to,
        `couple` = concat('$from','|','$to')'";
```

Comment: I still have the same result even with a unique key t allow multiple records

Comment: but when you echo your query it looks fine?

Comment: yeah but it should insert once, and now I can insert how many times I want