# how to match two rows of mysql same table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a Table in which rows can be added if needed by add button. i have two tables in my database product_size and product_color. Product_color table has column that contains size id. I am trying to do that if two or more rows value are same in size table e.g "small" then it should insert same size_id to the color table for all small colors. Please check my code and help if anyone can.
[image: product_size table]

product_color table
[image]

CODE:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['size']); $i++){

        $size = $_POST['size'][$i];          

        $qry1="INSERT INTO product_size (product_size) VALUES ('$size')";

        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$qry1);
        $product_size_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);                    


            $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'][$i];

            $color = $_POST['color'][$i];

            $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES ('$product_size_id', '$color', '$quantity')";

            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$qry2); 
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
            }
            else      
            {
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

//HTML CODE:

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color</b>&nbsp;</th>
                  <th><b>Quantity</b></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                  <td><select  name="size[]" id="size" required="" >
                  <option value="">Select Size</option></select></td>
                  <td>
                  <select name="color[]" required="" >
                    <option value="">Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Aqua">Aqua</option>   
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>   
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>    
                    <option value="Green">Green</option>   
                  </select></td>

                  <td>
                  <input style="width: 120px; height: 26px; " oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1" onchange="calculate();" min="1" max="1000" maxlength="4" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">  

                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </TABLE>
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

//HTML TABLE
[image]

Comment: It's because you're looping the `size` so it get `size++` on the next row. If your sizes are predefined in a table you don't need to loop it just pull the data and put on your form and then read the value from the submitted data then put it in to your color table.

Comment: i am inserting values from html table so looping size is must so that it can insert all rows values

Comment: then you wont be able to match your product ID's because the loop will always add 1 more to the value

Comment: how it can be done any hint?

Comment: As I said if you have your sizes in a table then use that data to create a drop down or a radio button select. Then send the selected value to your PHP then add the data to your table. If can post your `HTML` as well so it will be easy to answer once we see your input.

Comment: Check above my html table

Comment: Your code is wide-open to SQL injection!  Always sanitise and validate user provided input (Anything that comes from $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, etc) and never build SQL queries with string concatenation.  Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Moon not the table your `HTML` code is what we need to see

Comment: echo $_POST['size']; and check which values it contains?

Comment: @Sand  please check html code i edited

Comment: The $size array should contain [79,79,81] cause the value of small will be same not different.

Comment: @Mahfuz Shishir  i am trying that if sizes are same then id must not update and remain same

Comment: Your code said you are inserted not updated.

Comment: I'll try to help you m8 just give me few minutes to finish some work.

Comment: why don't you check if same product have same size already entered, before re-inserting?

Comment: Can you tell me which data contain of your $_POST['size'] when you select from html [Small, Small, Medium] like your screenshot?

Comment: it contains sizes values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125727/mysql-combined-unique-keys this will help you

Comment: @Kiran Shakya i don't want to skip the entry if value is same. i want that if valu is same e.g small then it adds same product_id for both not new

Comment: @Sand ok i am waiting

Comment: simply select the row with same `product_id` and `product_size` and if it returns a row, then insert new color with its `product_size_id`. You don't need to re-insert same size for same product.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149794/inserting-child-table-multiple-rows-across-parent-table-single-row-in-php @Kiran Shakya please check this and help if you can

Answer (score 1):

First of you need to create a table which will have all the sizes you want. The size table should have only id for the size and a name for the size then use that table to create your size drop down.

Then do something like this on your HTML table page.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con,"login");

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM size");
$sizeParam = $database->query($query);
$sizeParam -> execute();
?>
```

then in your HTML:

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Select&nbsp;</th>    
     <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Size</b>&nbsp;</th>
     <th style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;<b>Color</b>&nbsp;</th>
     <th><b>Quantity</b></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id='C1' class='customer'>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
   <td>
    <select  name="size[]" id="size" required="" >
     <option value="">Select Size</option></select></td>
    <?php while($getSizeRow = $sizeParam -> fetch_assoc()){ ?>
      <option id="<?php echo $getSizwRow["sizeId"]; ?>"><?php echo $getSizwRow["sizeId"]; ?></option></select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <select name="color[]" required="" >
      <option value="">Select Color</option>
      <option value="Aqua">Aqua</option>   
      <option value="Blue">Blue</option>   
      <option value="Black">Black</option>    
      <option value="Green">Green</option>   
     </select></td>
   <td>
     <input style="width: 120px; height: 26px; " oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" name="dress_quantity[]" class="qty1" onchange="calculate();" min="1" max="1000" maxlength="4" placeholder="Size Quantity" value="" required="">  
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</TABLE>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

Now when you receive the data on to your processing PHP do something like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 

        $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'];
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $size = $_POST['size'];

        $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $result2= $con -> prepare($qry2);
        $result2 -> bind_param(isi, $product_size_id, $color, $quantity);

        if($result2 -> execute()){
         echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
         echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
        }else{
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
       }
   }
}
```

This might contain errors this is the basic idea and I'm not much fluent with `mysqli_*` so if there's any let me know to correct them.